# Button collision event vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make some buttons move around in a rapid manner. Each click of a specific button should "reward" the player with a certain quantity of points (both positive or negative). This is a similar idea to some of the aspects in some of the "idiot test games" you see online.

How can I perform collision checks with the buttons?

I know it's possible with picture boxes to perform event collisions, with the following code `picObject1.bounds.intersectsWith(picObject2.bounds)`.
However, when I tried using that function for buttons, they didn't register as a collision. I do not know if that is because buttons don't have bounds (though that doesn't sound right) or due to some other hidden detail that I have missed.

Any pointers in the right direction would be extremely useful!

Comment: Not reproducible. Button.Bounds.IntersectWith works as expected.

Comment: Descriptions are great and all, but code is what's needed to diagnose problems. Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `Click` event for the buttons. The code might look something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private PlayerScore As Integer = 0
    Private Buttons() As Button

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Buttons = Enumerable.Range(0,10).
          Select(Function(i)          
             i = New Button()
             AddHandler i.Click, AddressOf ScoreClick
             Me.Controls.Add(i)
             Return i
          End Function)           
    End Sub

    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Private Sub ScoreClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
       PlayerScore += rnd.Next(-10, 10)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Now just add a timer to to the form to move the buttons around.